# What is a Twitter Bootstrap UI?

Tags: user-interface, twitter-bootstrap, development-environment, user-experience

I recently came across this term and I was wondering if there is anyone that could enlighten this concept and how it could fit into application development?

Comment: Could they have been talking about Twitter's CSS/JS framework called "Bootstrap"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Twitter Bootstrap

You're probably reffering to `Twitter Bootstrap`. Not to be confused with normal `bootstrap`, which is something else.

Twitter bootstrap is a small (frontend) css/js "framework" with which you can build fluid web pages. So this is meant for web design only.

This means that when you resize your browser, all elements will be resized aswell, so that it even displays everything nicely on a mobile device.

For examples and more information check out their github page: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/

## What is bootstrapping? (bootstrap)

Bootstrap (or bootstrapping) is something different. A bootstrap is a piece of code that is run when the machine (or application) first starts. A bootstrap file contains all sorts of standard configurations to configure itself.

There's actually more detail behind the whole bootstrap story, so for more information please read the wikipedia article:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrap

Comment: @Thilo In short, it's a piece of code that is run when the application starts, to configre itself.

Comment: Just an add on: you can also build non-fluid, non-responsive pages with Bootstrap; in fact, the responsive stuff is an enable-when-you-want-it rather than a disable-when-you-don't feature.

Answer (score 1):

### Bootstrap(aka Twitter Bootstrap)

- It is a ***powerful front-end(CSS,JS) framework*** for faster and
  easier  web development.
- It contains ***HTML and CSS-based design templates*** for
  typography, forms, buttons, navigation and other interface
  components, as well as optional ***JavaScript extensions***.
- It is ***compatible with all browsers*** from mobile to desktop
  platform.
- Since version 2.0 it also supports ***responsive design***. This
  means the ***layout of web pages adjusts dynamically***, taking into
  account the characteristics of the device used (PC, tablet, mobile
  phone).

Its ***open source*** and its hosted on [GitHub](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap)

To know [more](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/)

Answer (score -1):

Actually, the people giving the prior answers themselves did not have knowledge of the term and mistakenly, provided to you something *"that is more popular"*.

**Bootstrap UI** is also called ***Angular UI***. This is a JavaScript Library that is used for enhancing features used in projects using both - Bootstrap + Angular. It synchronized between them regarding pagination and other stuff. It is useful for projects primarily using Angular.

See here more details:

https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-correctly-use-bootstrapjs-and-angularjs-together

Thanks, buddy!